# About returning an uninitialized variable (C/Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, c

If I try returning an uninitialized variable, will it guarantee the value is always null/zero?

For example:

```
struct Rect rect_with_zero_value(){
    struct Rect aRect;
    return aRect; // Will `aRect` always contain 0 value inside the C struct?
}

void * nullPointer(){
    void * pointer;
    return pointer; // Will `pointer` always be `Null`?
}
```

---

**Updated**

I find a way to ensure the returning value is always null/zero for any return type except the type `void`:

```
#define returnNullValue(ReturnType) \
    ReturnType retVal; \
    memset(&retVal, 0, sizeof(ReturnType)); \
    return retVal

struct Rect rect_with_zero_value(){
    returnNullValue(struct Rect); // Return a rect struct which contains 0 value.
}

void * nullPointer(){
    returnNullValue(void *);
}
```

Because I am doing metaprogramming using C macros, I need to find a universal way to ensure the returning value is always null/zero if it is not. And I think this is the solution. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I try returning an uninitialized variable, will it guarantee the value is always null/zero?

No, at least not for C.

Moreover: Returning an uninitialised variable implicitly provokes Undefined Behaviour, as returning the value implies reading the (local and uninitialised) variable, which in turn provokes the UB.

Always initialise variables on definition:

```
struct Rect rect_with_zero_value() {
  struct Rect aRect = {0};
  return aRect; 
}

void * nullPointer() {
  void * pointer = NULL;
  return pointer; 
}
```

If you do not know to which value to initialise the variables, you propably do not need them at all.

Answer (score 3):

No. They are not zero.

Only static and global variables have zero value on initialization, for example:

```
void * nullPointer(){
    static void * pointer;
    return pointer; // Now pointer is null
}
```

or

```
void *pointer; //pointer is null
void * nullPointer(){

    return pointer; 
}
```

Comment: Be careful. While you're of course correct that making a variable static or global means it will be initialized to zero, it's too easy for a naive reader to mistake that as advice for how to improve their program. They should not change their variables to static or global unless and until they really understand what such changes mean. It is not a means to avoid having to explicitly initialize a variable that should remain local and with automatic lifetime.

Comment: @KenThomases Good point. I think your comment is an enough good warning for everybody that reads my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Object pointers are also initialized to nil, that was a change made a couple of years ago to Objective-C. But the best advice: Explicitly initialize all variables, it will help the next developer more easily understand the code and potential eliminate strange errors if a variable is not initialized that needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

No. If it had a guaranteed value, it would be initialized.

An uninitialized variable contains semi-random junk.

Comment: Please, what means "semi-random"?

Comment: You should consider the junk to be random. But, in truth, there are some predictable patterns to the kind of junk that will be in an uninitialized variable, so it's not truly random. That's why I called it "semi-random", meaning "meaningless and arbitrary, but not truly random and unpredictable".